# Inherit from data types

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

How to create a class which inherits from a data type, specifically from Char data type? I just wan't to add one property to it. If it's not possible, are there any other ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't think you could inherit from System types.

Remember an extension method can be only a Sub procedure or a Function procedure. You cannot define an extension property, field, or event.

Your options:

- Extension method (can only be a function or sub)
- A custom structure (use Reflector to make your own custom Char)
- A class that takes System.Char is input and allows you to store the Char and your extra property. You will need to implement your own `IsLetter` and the like.

Quick and dirty example (you may want to make this `Static` by placing it in a `Module` instead):

```
Class MyChar

  Sub New()
  End Sub
  Sub New(byval input As System.Char)
    Me.[Char] = input
  End Sub
  Sub New(byval input As String)
    Me.Parse(input)
  End Sub

  Public Property [Char] As System.Char
  Public Property ExtraProperty As String

  Public ReadOnly Property IsLetter As Boolean
    Get
        return Me.[Char].IsLetter(Me.[Char])
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Function Parse(ByVal input As String)
    If (input Is Nothing) Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("input")
    End If
    If (input.Length <> 1) Then
        Throw New FormatException("Need a single character only")
    End If
    Me.[Char] = input.Chars(0)
  End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

Deriving from System.Char would be madness and a useless effort. [Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) to the rescue.

Comment: This is also available to visual basic?

Comment: @Cobold, sure, I've updated my answer to point to the VB.NET part of the documentation.

Comment: Is there a way to add a property? Looks like it's not allowed.

Comment: @Cobold, no there isn't. Only methods. I think extension properties will be added in vNext.